# Error in start virtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I got this error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine win7.
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I run it before. but when I again start it, I got that error!!!

this is my system situation:

- Ubuntu 18 on my computer (64b)
- windows 7 on my VirtualBox
- in VirtualBox PAN/NX is Enable
- in Bios Virtualization Technology is Enable (Bellow picture)
- allocated RAM to VirtualBox is 2048 MB

this is answer of sudo kvm-ok:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
  and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

[image]

Comment: The message is explicit. You need to enable virtulzation in your BIOS.  https://bce.berkeley.edu/enabling-virtualization-in-your-pc-bios.html or similar

Comment: What does mean this in that link @Panther :  Delete any existing VMs (Machine > Remove ** and select ** Delete all files) and re-import the .ova file

Comment: You need to enable virtulzation in your BIOS.  I did not tell you to delete anything. Google search your bios

Comment: Yes it should work now

Comment: You need to post details

Comment: Same error or different?

Comment: I  had enabled virtualization in my BIOS before I sent the question.

Comment: If you are still getting the same error message it is a hardware problem or misconfigured BIOS settings. You can not fix this from ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I wanted to enable virtualization, I reset my computer and do it. It does not work. Today I notice that "sudo kvm-ok" said, "poweroff/poweron your system". I try this instead of restarting and it works!!!!

I didn't think maybe restart being different from poweroff/poweron!!!!